# How to force HTTPS with htaccess file if all requests routed through index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a code in my htaccess file to route every request which in not a file or a directory to index.php the code is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I edit this code to force all requests also to be https?

I tried to search the forum, but couldn't find an answer to my current question.

Comment: Duplicate question. Already answered:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding the HTTPS enforcement rule before your routing rule it should look something like that if am not mistaken

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# HTTPS enforcement
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L] 
#if it didn't work with [L] try adding [L,R=301] instead

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

here is a kinda similar question in stackoverFlow that was answered in 2012 [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028954/htaccess-redirects-to-https-with-index-php)

Comment: don't answer the duplicate questions. Read community guidelines. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. It worked with [L]. I saw the similar post. But wasn't sure how to combine the two.